# Visual Studio Test Explorer Icons

Tags: visual-studio, test-explorer

I've searched around and can't seem to find any reference to the light icon with the green check.

[image]

This [FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/test-explorer-faq?view=vs-2019) only shows the solid green with white check version.

The test output seems to be the same as the green icon with the white check - just passing tests. All of the tests in the groups have run successfully, so it isn't like a partial run or something.

Does anybody know the difference in the icons?

Comment: They indicate passing/failing tests which weren't included in the last run.

Comment: Thanks.  If you want to throw that in an answer, I will accept it. @phuzi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They indicate passing/failing tests which weren't included in the last run.